# Filter for relation type and value in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I think that Neo4J is the correct way to resolve my problem but I'm not able to do a query for my scenario.
My demo data are:

```
CREATE 
(`O1` :O { name:'O1' }) ,
(`E1` :E { name:'E1' }) ,
(`M1` :M { name:'M1' }) ,
(`O2` :O { name:'O2' }) ,
(`L1` :L { name:'L1' }) ,
(`E2` :E { name:'E2' }) ,
(`E1`)-[:`O<->E` {name:'O<->E', T:'T1'}]->(`O1`),
(`M1`)-[:`O<->M` {name:'O<->M',T:'T0'}]->(`O1`),
(`O1`)-[:`O<->L` {name:'O<->L',T:'T0'}]->(`L1`),
(`E1`)-[:`O<->E` {name:'O<->E',T:'T2'}]->(`O2`),
(`O1`)-[:`O<->E` {name:'O<->E',T:'T3'}]->(`E2`)
```

[Sample Data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIakp.jpg)

All relationships are bidirectional. The relation direction is mandatory for the create statement but is not useful for my scenario.

The rules are:
Find node nearest (property on relation) the input parameter but only one relation for type (very confused statement).

To clarify, if the input parameters are:

```
E1 on T2 the correct answer is: O2 
O1 on T2 the correct answer is: M1, L1
O1 on T1 the correct answer is: M1, E1, L1
O1 on T3 the correct answer is: M1, E2, L1
```

[explanation for E1 on T2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Fxr.jpg)

[explanation for O1 on T2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Mgv.jpg)

[explanation for O1 on T1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB3ry.jpg)

[explanation for O1 on T3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1TRK.jpg)

With my query, I'm able to retrieve all node with correct T but I'm not able to apply the rule to have only one relation for each relation type.

```
MATCH p=(order:Order {name:'O1'})-[r*0..5]-() 
where ALL(r IN relationships(p) WHERE r.T <= 'T3') 
RETURN nodes(p)
```

EDIT:

I tried to resolve "O1 on T2" with this query but I'm not able to create a single query with following statements (I should select a "top 1 where" for each relation type and after all search the path):

```
MATCH (n)-[r:`O<->E`]-(m) WHERE r.T <= "T2" RETURN ID(r) ORDER BY r.T 
DESC LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
MATCH (n)-[r:`O<->L`]-(m) WHERE r.T <= "T2" RETURN ID(r) ORDER BY r.T 
DESC LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
MATCH (n)-[r:`O<->M`]-(m) WHERE r.T <= "T2" RETURN ID(r) ORDER BY r.T 
DESC LIMIT 1
<-RETRIEVE RESULT (In this example the ids are 47,48,49) AND CREATE SUBQUERY TO EXECUTE FOLLOWING STATEMENT ->
MATCH p = (e:O {name:'O1'})-[r*..5]-(z) WHERE ALL(r IN relationships(p) WHERE ID(r) = 47 OR ID(r) = 48 OR ID(r) = 49)
RETURN z
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to clarify this...I'm not following your requirements. Can you explain in more depth why the inputs you're providing should output those answers?

Comment: I updated the post with some image to clarify my requirements

Comment: These requirements are still very confusing. Here's my understanding for each of these 4 examples: #1. Starting from E1, the only two relationships have the same type, so we can only keep one of these. I don't understand why rel to O2 is chosen instead of rel to O1. Doesn't T1 come first alphabetically? What is the order you are using? For #2, I get why the O<->M and O<->L rels are chosen, but I'm not following why no O<->E is chosen. Don't you need one of each rel type? Also T1 is less than your upper limit of T2.

Comment: #3 seems to make sense, you get the three distinct rels based on type, and you choose the one to E1 because T1 <= T1, which disqualifies the rel to E2. #4 I don't understand, since you're going up to T3 I would have thought the T1 rel would have been chosen first. Or is your ordering supposed to be descending from your chosen T value for the rels?

Comment: In my simplification I create confusion. T1, T2, T3 are the time when the relationships are built. The active is the latest compared with the parameter inputs. When a new relationship has been created the older is not valid anymore. What I want is to retrieve the system status in a certain time like a snapshot.
For #2, the rule is that in the possible path (O1-E1-O2), in the node E1 exists two relations of the same type and in this case the active relation (T2 is nearest of the inputs parameter) is from E1 to O2 and the relation from O1 and E1 is removed and the path is broken.
Thanks.

Comment: I updated the post with a new query but I'm not able to complete the task.